# how to figure out compile 'com.android.support:design:23.1.1'

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin

How I can figure out `compile 'com.android.support:design:23.1.1'`
what should i write in my gradle there??? how can i figure out what is the latest design support library number? how can i figure out whats one i need to use?

same for `compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.4.0'`

and lets assume i want to include external library, how shall it be done?

```
compile(name:'estimote-sdk', ext:'aar')
```

something like that?

thank you for all the help. i am new to android studio migrating from eclipse

Comment: Define "figure out" ... `compile 'com.android.support:design:23.1.1'` is exactly what you put into Gradle. If you want the latest version, then [search for it](http://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/index.html)

Answer (score 1):

You can use this `'com.android.support:design:+'` but it is not recommended because it is unpredictable.

For me Android Studio tells me that I'm not using the latest and offers autofix.

Answer (score 0):

Let me share how I do it... It may help...

First, I pay attention when Android Studio request to update any of the SDK Package.

So, either if support library was updated or Play Service was updated, I check those their release notes to get the proper version (**you may want to check the release notes as well to discover what is new etc**):

[Here](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/support-library/revisions.html) and [here](https://developers.google.com/android/guides/releases)

This site show the package version for each Play Service API: [here](https://developers.google.com/android/guides/setup)

But as JBarat  already mentioned on the other answer, Android Studio will suggest the value based on the package installed in your SDK.

Answer (score 0):

> how can i figure out what is the latest design support library number?

*if there is new version avilable of support library then android studio give you warning like below*

[image]

> how can i figure out what's one i need to use?

suggestion to use letest support(design,v7,v4,recycleview..etc) library because new one have less bug then previous. you can also use new futures if they have added something new to support library.

*take look in to [**Support Library Features**](http://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/features.html) & [**Support Library change-logs**](http://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/index.html) depend on these you are able to choose appropriate support library version.*